# Bot Framework: Enable PromptDialog.Text to be spoken by cortana

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, cortana

I need to get Cortana to read all my prompts, so far I managed to get it to speak simple phrases like in this example:

```
[LuisIntent("Thanks")]
public async Task Thanks(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
{

    await context.SayAsync(text: Phrases.YOURE_WELCOME, speak: Phrases.YOURE_WELCOME);
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

}
```

But I can't do this on PromptDialogs.Text
I have this code:

```
private async Task OnCustomerSet(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{

    string name = await result;
    PromptDialog.Text(context, OnNIFSet, Phrases.ASK_CUSTOMER_NIF);

}
```

How can I get Cortana to also speak this prompt?

Thanks.

Comment: After looking through the SDK there would have to be changes made in the SDK itself to get this to work.  This must have been an oversight when designing prompts.  There is not going to be a simple solution to this.  You could try overriding the `PromptChoice.text` to make it accept `PromptOptions` but this gets messy pretty quickly.  You could simply try sending a `context.SayAsync` right before you send your prompt.  It's a total hack but it might work for you.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it doesn't work because the phrase gets shown twice and If I leave it "" or null it shows a 0, at elast on the emulator, haven't tried to see what it shows in Cortana.

Comment: It seemed to only show it once when I was testing in Cortana, but it was not a very elaborate test

Comment: I've been trying to send a context.SayAsync before the prompt but Cortana isnt reading it, In fact it seems as if it just skips the SayAsync since it doesnt even display the text.

Comment: I managed to do it by using context.SayAsync twice, Cortana seems to ignore the one before the prompt.

Comment: That is interesting becuase I was simply using `string text = "This is a text prompt";
                await context.SayAsync(text);
                PromptDialog.Text(context, Afterprompt, text);` and cortana was reading it

Comment: @Bruna Alves, I am going to look at adding this to the SDK in the near future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:  I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/4714) to have this added to the C# SDK and upon the next release it will be part of the bot.builder package. The current release is 3.15.2.2 (at the time of writing this) so anything higher than that should have it.  it will be in the SDK so you will not have to use the method in this answer.**

After looking deeper into this, I was able to come up with a solution that will work without changes to the SDK and I have confirmed this is already working in node out of the box.  I will add the changes in a pull request still, but this should help you for now.

You can make a class that will inherit from `PromptDialog` and make a constructor for a PromptDialog.text like this:

```
public class PromptDialogTextSpeak:PromptDialog
{
    public static void Text(IDialogContext context, ResumeAfter<string> resume, IPromptOptions<string> promptOptions)
    {
        var child = new PromptString(promptOptions);
        context.Call<string>(child, resume);
    }
}
```

I was able to get this working with a simple prompt such as:

```
 var text = "this is a prompt";
PromptOptions<string> qwerty = new PromptOptions<string>(text, speak: text);
PromptDialogTextSpeak.Text(context, AfterPrompt, qwerty);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a speak attribute to the prompt Option and use the SSML Helper to read out the prompt dialog.

```
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions<string>(
                Resources.ChooseSides,
                choices: choices,
                descriptions: descriptions,
                speak: SSMLHelper.Speak(Utils.RandomPick(Resources.ChooseSidesSSML))); // spoken prompt

PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.DiceChoiceReceivedAsync, promptOptions);
```

Please refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-cortana-skill?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#explore-the-code) for the details and the [GitHub Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-RollerSkill).
If you need additional help do ask ;)

Comment: But that solution works only for PromptDialog.Choice and PromptDialog.Confirm. The PromptDialog.Text doesn't accept PromptOptions as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry I missed out on that.